# Swift: can I pass a UIView as an argument that I can create/modify?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I have a UIView I declared globally:

```
var speedView: UIView!
```

then I have a function that takes an UIView as an argument and creates it:

```
func buildView(view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100))
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work because the `view` argument is automatically set to `let` which you can't modify.

A workaround is to define it as `var view...` like this:

```
func buildView(var view: UIView!) -> UIView { ... }
```

By doing this it technically works but later if I want to go and modify `self.speedView` I can't access it because it was never really created by that function.

So this:

```
self.buildView(self.speedView)
```

Won't really create `self.speedView` I think.

Any ideas how I can do have a function that takes some globally defined views as arguments, create them and then I can still access those globally defined views?

Comment: Why are you defining views globally?

Comment: `inout` maybe, are you looking for here?

Comment: @damian because I want to access and modify them later on. not just UIViews also UILabels

Comment: Right, but why global? They should belong to a ViewController, and you should let iOS decide when to construct and destroy ViewControllers (so that it can sanely manage memory usage for you). By having global variables, you deny it of that ability.

Comment: @damian yeah sorry, I meant globally in the controller, right after `class SomeController {`

Answer (score 3):

Ok so the best solution was to use `inout` and `&` like below:

```
func buildView(inout view: UIView!) -> UIView { ... }
```

and then can the function like this:

```
self.buildView(&self.speedView)
```

You place an ampersand (&) directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to an inout parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function.

Answer (score 0):

the parameters are constant by default - a 'let' if you want

in most cases this is 100% ok and you shouldn't modify parameters

---

now as you want a VAR instead, use a `inout` parameter .. no Idea WHY though but that way you can modify it

Comment: `inout` when I define it or in the function arguments? the compiler is not very happy with either of those...

Comment: func(inout myVar:Type)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you want new view? Whats about this:

```
import UIKit

class MVViewController11: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var speedView: UIView!
    @IBAction func buttonSelected(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.buildView(self.speedView)
    }

    func buildView(var view: UIView!) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 10, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Works for me:

```
import UIKit

class MVViewController11: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var speedView: UIView!
    @IBAction func buttonSelected(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.buildView(self.speedView)
    }
    @IBAction func button2Selected(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.builView2(self.speedView)
    }

    @IBAction func button3Selected(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.speedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }
    func buildView(var view: UIView!) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    func builView2(var view: UIView!) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}
```

Note: speedView is connected via Interface Builder.

Comment: but what if later on there's another function that changes the background color of the view, like: `self.speedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() `? I would get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`